(x != x) for default equality operator==
This program
struct A {
    int i = 0;
    constexpr operator int() const { return i; }
    constexpr operator int&() { return ++i; }
};

struct B {
    A a;
    bool operator==(const B &) const = default;
};

constexpr bool f() {
    B x;
    return x == x;
}

static_assert( f() ); // fails in GCC

fails static assertion in GCC compiler, meaning that x != x is true during constant evaluation, where operator== is generated by the compiler. Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4xjTnM54M
If one modifies struct B such that it inherits from A instead of having it as a field:
struct B : A {
    bool operator==(const B &) const = default;
};

constexpr bool f() {
    B x;
    return x == x;
}

static_assert( f() ); // fails in Clang

then the program succeeds in GCC but fails in Clang. Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5hYob3K66
Are both programs well formed and f() must be evaluated to true?

constexpr B x; static_assert( x == x ); will fail as well in GCC, and will give a better error message. Perhaps it's the other two compilers that are wrong?

gcc's error message with const B x; looks suspicious to me (why does it insist on using the non-const conversion?). I'll vote for a gcc bug.

@Someprogrammerdude GCC doesn't look right. It apparently attempts to call A::operator int&(), which is not marked const, on a const object.

Why is A::operator int&() incrementing i?

@RemyLebeau, thanks, not-const method is allowed to make increments of member fields (in real program before reduction it counts the number of operator calls). The question is more about whether the compiler may call a not-const method from within another const method.

more readable live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/ePdcj6cdr

No, a const method cannot call a non-const method - the types of the this pointer are different and not convertible.

This is just a bug in GCC/Clang.
A defaulted equality operator is specified to perform a memberwise equality comparison of its operands' base class subobjects, followed by non-static data members, in declaration order ([class.eq]/3).
The comparison is performed as-if by a == b, where a and b are lvalues denoting the corresponding subobjects of the operands. [class.compare.default]/5 explicitly says that such lvalues are

formed by a sequence of derived-to-base conversions, class member access expressions, and array subscript expressions applied to x

where x is the respective parameter of the defaulted equality operator, which is necessarily const-qualified.
So, following the normal rules of the language, a and b should also inherit this const-qualification (except when referring to mutable data members), but for some reason this does not happen in GCC for non-static data members, whereas Clang coincidentally exhibits the same buggy behavior with base class subobjects.
In the OP example, this bug leads to A::operator int&() being selected over A::operator int() const to perform the A->int conversion for the built-in operator==(int, int).
